# Listbox with checkboxes — description aligment with title, or checkbox?

Tags: checkboxes, grouped-list

[image]

On a project, we show a list with checkboxes — and all options have some additional descriptions. So the question is should those descriptions be left aligned with the checkbox, or item title?

Answer (score 0):

I like looking at these types of layouts as if they were bulleted lists with checkboxes for bullets.

See this example:

> **Benefits of exercise:**
>
> - Boosts mood
> - Increases energy
> - Improves sleep
> - Helps control weight by elevating your metabolic rate, which allows you to burn more calories even when you're at rest.
> - Enhances mental clarity by stimulating the release of chemicals in the brain that can improve memory, focus, and problem-solving skills.

As you can see, lists usually use this typographical pattern called *[hanging indent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_(typesetting))* (or *negative indent*).

I think it'd help make your checkbox list read as both a list and selection options group and, more importantly, make it [more scannable](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/text-scanning-patterns-eyetracking/) and easier to use. It also helps [visually group](https://lawsofux.com/law-of-proximity/) description with the label, which is better too.

So overall, I usually go with the first option.